Ros2 gazebo robot_localization ackermann
I’m trying to setup an ackermann robot. Could anyone help me to diagnose the problem shown below. I followed the nav2 gps waypoint follower tutorial which uses turtlebot https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html (seems to be offline at the time i’m writing this). I swapped turtlebot model with a four wheel ackermann one, switching from differential to libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive plugin. When sending /cmd_vel
ros2 topic pub -r 30 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/msg/Twist "{linear: {x: 0.5, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0}}"

model in gazebo seems to act as expected, it runs in circle.
When i start an instance of robot localization as well, i can see that front wheels are twisted, but model most of the time moves in direction of base link is heading. Robot path now reminds of a rectangle with rounded corners instead of a circle.I’m using IMU for heading and GPS for localization, no wheel encoders.


Part of model description
    <!--              ackermann plugin                 -->    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_ackermann_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive.so">

        <ros>
          <!--<namespace>/demo</namespace>-->
            <!--since gazebo_plugins publish tf topic in global namespace /tf only and it
            cannot be remapped like (namespace/tf) through launch arguments -->
          <remapping>/tf:=tf</remapping>
        </ros>

        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>

        <!-- wheels -->
        <front_left_joint>front_left_wheel</front_left_joint>
        <front_right_joint>front_right_wheel</front_right_joint>
        <rear_left_joint>rear_left_wheel</rear_left_joint>
        <rear_right_joint>rear_right_wheel</rear_right_joint>
        <left_steering_joint>front_left_steering</left_steering_joint>
        <right_steering_joint>front_right_steering</right_steering_joint>
        <steering_wheel_joint>main_steering</steering_wheel_joint>

        <!-- Max absolute steer angle for tyre in radians-->
        <!-- Any cmd_vel angular z greater than this would be capped -->
        <max_steer>0.6458</max_steer>

        <!-- Max absolute steering angle of steering wheel -->
        <max_steering_angle>7.85</max_steering_angle>

        <!-- Max absolute linear speed in m/s -->
        <max_speed>20</max_speed>

        <!-- PID tuning -->

         <left_steering_pid_gain>10 0 1</left_steering_pid_gain>
        <left_steering_i_range>0 0</left_steering_i_range>
        <right_steering_pid_gain>10 0 1</right_steering_pid_gain>
        <right_steering_i_range>0 0</right_steering_i_range>
        <linear_velocity_pid_gain>0.5 0 0</linear_velocity_pid_gain>
        <linear_velocity_i_range>0 0</linear_velocity_i_range>     

        <!-- output -->

        <!-- The odom -> base link transform is published by the ekf in robot localization -->
        <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
        <publish_odom_tf>false</publish_odom_tf>
        <publish_wheel_tf>false</publish_wheel_tf>

        <odometry_topic>odom</odometry_topic>
        <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
        <robot_base_frame>base_footprint</robot_base_frame>        
      </plugin>

      <plugin name="solbot_joint_state" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
        <ros>
            <remapping>~/out:=joint_states</remapping>
        </ros>
        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
        <joint_name>front_left_wheel</joint_name>
        <joint_name>front_right_wheel</joint_name>
        <joint_name>rear_left_wheel</joint_name>
        <joint_name>rear_right_wheel</joint_name>        

        <joint_name>front_left_steering</joint_name>
        <joint_name>front_right_steering</joint_name>
        <joint_name>main_steering</joint_name>   

      </plugin>      

  </gazebo>

Robot localization parameters file
ekf_filter_node_odom:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: true # Recommended to use 2d mode for nav2 in mostly planar environments
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: true
    publish_tf: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_footprint # the frame id used by the turtlebot's diff drive plugin
    world_frame: odom

    imu0: imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false,  true,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false  # If using a real robot you might want to set this to true, since usually absolute measurements from real imu's are not very accurate
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: true  # Recommended to use 2d mode for nav2 in mostly planar environments
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false
    publish_tf: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_footprint # the frame id used by the turtlebot's diff drive plugin
    world_frame: map

    odom0: odom
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, true, true,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    odom1: odometry/gps
    odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 10
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: false

    imu0: imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false  # If using a real robot you might want to set this to true, since usually absolute measurements from real imu's are not very accurate
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1.0,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0
    yaw_offset: 0.0
    zero_altitude: true
    broadcast_utm_transform: true
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: true
    wait_for_datum: false 


A bunch of things, in no particular order:

In your ekf_filter_node_odom instance, you have two_d_mode set to true. However, in your IMU config, you are fusing pitch and yaw. Pitch will be ignored.
You only input to the ekf_filter_node_odom is an IMU, and you are measuring only two dimensions (really one, as I mentioned above). That is going to cause the state estimate covariance to explode, which will do ugly things to the state estimate itself. You need some kind of reference here for X and/or X velocity, and Y and/or Y velocity. You already have yaw from the IMU, so that's fine.
You also are fusing pitch and yaw from your odom0 source in ekf_filter_node_map, but you have two_d_mode on there as well.
Furthermore, your ekf_filter_node_map instance is fusing yaw from your IMU as well. If that doesn't agree with your odom0 yaw, the filter will rapidly jump back and forth between them.


but model most of the time moves in direction of base link is heading

That's how the kinematics work. The EKF's internal motion model is omnidirectional; in 2D, with 0 velocity in Y, the math boils down to the unicycle model. We don't have Ackermann kinematics in the EKF, so you need to provide Ackermann pose data at a high enough rate to overcome the effect of the kinematic model predictions.
EDIT: Sorry, another (possibly better) option is to increase the process_noise_covariance for the pose dimensions (X, Y, and yaw).

Thanks automatom,

so you need to provide Ackermann pose data at a high enough rate to
overcome the effect of the kinematic model predictions.

that made me play around with gazebo world parameters and
Increasing gazebos physics real_time_update_rate from 100 to 1000
and decreasing max_step_size from 0.01 to 0.001 solved it.
